# Get a list of contacts using cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Sorry for my bad English.

How to get a list of contacts by using the Cordova angularjs?

Thanks in advance. Kind regards.

Comment: take a look on this one:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your cordova-app is built up and but you could do it this way( take into consideration that I've not tested this):

Code:

1. First request contacts of your device by using the condact-plugin of cordova:
   (same link as provided earlier: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html)

   ```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   function onDeviceReady() {

      // when using the plugin:
      // you can put it within your angularjs-controllers 
      // where it will be executed and onSuccess-callback is called.
      var options = new ContactFindOptions();
      options.filter = "";
      options.multiple=true; 
      var fields = ["displayName", "name"];

      navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);

   }

   // within this function you have to assign contacts to a model
   function onSuccess(contacts) {
      $scope.contacts = contacts;
   }


   function onError(contactError) {
      alert('onError!');
   }
   ```

HTML:

2. Iterate over each contact-object of your contacts-collection assigned within onSuccess-function:

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">{{contact.name.formatted}}</div>
   ```

Tutorial: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-way-to-get-all-contacts-using-PhoneGap-on-Android

Putting the plugin into a angularjs-controller could look like this:

```
angular.module('aModule', [])

.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.multiple = true;
        options.filter = "";
        var fields = ["displayName", "name"];

        navigator.contacts.find(fields, 
            function(contacts){ 

                var arr = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
                {
                  arr.push({name: contacts[i].name.formatted})
                }
                $scope.contacts = arr;

            }, 
            function(error){ console.log(error); },
            options
        );

}])
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="aModule" ng-controller="contactCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">{{contact.name}}</div>
</div>
```